# vuejs - loop for in list A marking checked when items are present in list B

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm looping a list with all available items and checkboxes so can user can select those he want.

Example of `allAtivos` data:

```
"allAtivos": [
  { "id": 1, "title": "Amazon" },
  { "id": 2, "title": "Google" },
]
```

So my difficult is that I need to compare another data structure to know which items are already selected.

Example of user's `myAtivos` data (look that `Ativo` item is a sub-object):

```
"myAtivos": [
  {
    "ativo": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Amazon",
    }
  }
]
```

This is how I'm trying to do:

```
<label class="item" v-for="(item, i) in allAtivos" :key="item.id">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="myAtivos" :value="item.id" />
</label>
```

How can I display `allAtivos` list with already checked items when it's present in `myAtivos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with something like

```html
<label class="item" v-for="(item, i) in allAtivos" :key="item.id">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="myAtivos" :value="item.id" :checked="!!myAtivos.find(ativo => ativo.ativo && ativo.ativo.id === item.id)" />
</label>
```